# What is IEventRepository in this code? What does Resolver.resolve( ) do?

Tags: c#, javascript, sql, json, fullcalendar

```
public JsonResult GetEvents(double start, double end)
{
    var userName = Session["UserName"] as string;
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
    {
        return null;
    }
    var fromDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(start);
    var toDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(end);
    var rep = Resolver.Resolve<IEventRepository>();
    var events = rep.ListEventsForUser(userName,fromDate,toDate);
    var eventList = from e in events
                    select new {
                                id = e.Id,
                                title = e.Title,
                                start = e.FromDate.ToString("s"),
                                end = e.ToDate.ToString("s"),
                                allDay = false
                            };
    var rows = eventList.ToArray();
    return Json(rows,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);           
}
```

I have gotten this code from [this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/02/03/using-fullcalendar-jquery-component-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx) and am trying to make sense of it. What I would like to do is use the fullcalendar code to retrieve events from a database and allow users to add them to a database using C# and Razor. I think this code is close to what I would like in that it is creating the JSON object on the fly, but I need to adapt it to use SQL and C#. Can anyone help with this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's grabbing an instantiation of `IEventRepository` from the kernel/resolver of a dependency injection framework. Elsewhere in the code/configuration, there will be instructions for the resolver regarding what kind of object should be instantiated when asked for an object of type `IEventRepository`. Without seeing that code, it's anyone's guess as to what is being handed back from that call, other than it satisfies the interface `IEventRepository`. Likely, there's only one or two classes that implement `IEventRepository`. Find them!

If you want to read up on DI, I like the [ninject docs](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki), but this particular code doesn't look like ninject.

Comment: OK, I'm guessing that in this case I can execute a kind of workaround to achieve what I wish then. I could do away with this code, initiate a connection to my database and then loop around finding events for a particular user and storing the data produced in the eventList array? Do you think this is feasible for what I wish to do?

Comment: Yes, probably, but why the aversion to LINQ?

Comment: What is LINQ? To be honest I have never even heard of this; I have no idea how I would use it in my case.

Comment: @Simon: LINQ(Language Integrated Query) is very useful if you want to filter an output from a data set. Most of the ORMs use LINQ to retrieve data set from database and perform some task on that data set. Please go through this http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/Linq/.